# Access Coherence cached data cross WebLogic cluster tiers (Data-cache/EJB/Servlet)

Tags: servlets, caching, weblogic12c, multi-tier

I am trying configure a WebLogic 12cR2 cluster to support distributed data cache and application cross serial clustered nodes.

Clustering topology as:

```
1. Three separated weblogic clusters:
  a. Cluster-jpa (local storage enabled, used to hold distributed data  cache, it is JPA back mapped to PostgreSQL database - data tier), 
  b. Cluster-ejb (local storage disabled, used to hold business application (EJBs) - application tier)
  c. Cluster-web (Coherence Web Local storage enable, used to hold and replicate web session, it is servlet cluster - web tier)
2. One Coherence Cluster, name: Coherence-cluster, configured as multicast (clustering mode). Three separated WebLogic clusters (jpa, ejb and web ) were added to coherence cluster as members.
3. Two WebLogic managed servers configured:
  a. JPAServer, targeted to Cluster-jpa cluster, as Cluster-jpa was backboned with Coherence-Cluster, it is a managed coherence server as well. This managed server was used to hold Coherence Application (data tier), a ***.gar was deployed on this server, distributed cache objects and near cache was configured and works well.
  b. EJBServer, targeted to Cluster-ejb cluster, as Cluster-ejb was backboned with Coherence-Cluster as well, it is an other managed coherence server. This managed server will be used to hold WebLogic JavaEE applications (EJBs in ***.ear format) as separated application tier (in application cluster) to consume distributed coherence data cache to provide high performance and high available business logic service. I'm having difficult to configure EJB application (***.ear) now. I followed oracle developing guide to develop a JEE application and embed the cache definition gar file into the lib directory. But unfortunately, I didn't get it work. The issue maybe caused by: EJBServer stay in Cluster-ejb cluster but JPAServer stay in Cluster-jpa cluster.
4. Two or more domain partition configured: 
  a. Couple of virtual targets were defined and target to Cluster-web
  b. Couple of Domain partitions were defined and targeted to virtual targets, those domain partitions were used to hold web applications (servlet tier). Coherence will be used to hold and replicate web session to support failover. Web tier will access Coherence data cache through Application tier (This part is under developing.)
```

As WebLogic 12cR2 is still quite new, can't find a lots of good examples and tutorials. Does any one can share some idea about the development experience?

Answer (score 0):

I recently deployed an application using the latest Coherence version [12c R2]. It's all about the GAR file now.

This Blog post, helped me in my learning curve, I think it's worth looking at it.

Also, I uploaded a sample GAR file on my site so you can check it out and start from [there](http://ilansalviano.com.br/temp/testGAR.zip).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My Coherence managed cache server (coherence application in data tier, was targeted into weblogic cluster -  Cluster-jpa & backboned with Coherence-cluster) is working well. I am having difficult to access the cache from application tier (EJB application that included ***.gar) that stay in other weblogic cluster (targeted to Cluster-ejb and same backboned with Coherence-cluster).

Comment: Oh.. I see... If you want to make it work the way it is today, you should make you EJB application a member of the COH cluster you desire to interact with. Maybe you could try adding your EJB application as a WKA of the COH Cluster you wan to connect with.

Another approach, would be the ExtendedClient* approach. With turns you EJB application into a effective real time client (socket style) to the COH cluster.

Comment: Yeah. My EJB application (***.ear that ***.gar included) was deployed on a Weblogic Managed Server (EJBServer), EJBServer is a member of WebLogic Cluster (Cluster-ejb), Cluster-ejb is member of Coherence Cluster (Coherence-cluster).  My Coherence application (***.gar) was deployed on Cache server (JPAServer), JPAServer is a member of other WebLogic Cluster (Cluster-jpa), Cluster-jpa is member of Coherence Cluster (Coherence-cluster) as well. Such means EJB and GAR sharing same COH cluster.